# how to convert python array(List) to CSV

Tags: python

My csv output is not coming out the way I planned.  My code:

```
first_row = list(ws.rows)[1]
first_row_values = []
first_row_values.append(value1)
first_row_values.append(value2)
first_row_values.append(value3)
first_row_values.extend([cell.value for cell in first_row])
print(first_row_values)
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'a+'))
writer.writerow([first_row_values])
```

the output in the file looks like this:

```
"['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC', 'valueD', 'valueE', 'valueF', 'valueG', 'valueH', 'valueI', 'valueJ']"
```

I'm expecting a csv output:

```
'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC', 'valueD', 'valueE', 'valueF', 'valueG', 'valueH', 'valueI', 'valueJ'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: remove the `[]` around first_row_values in the last row.

Comment: Remove the square brackets in `writer.writerow([first_row_values])`.

Comment: `first_row_values` is already a list, now you made it into a nested list that is the first element of your row, so the whole things gets converted to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Mad Physicist and Anton vBR, the set of square brackets, `[]`, is the issue. When you put these brackets around something in python, it will create a list upon execution. So, by putting a list object, `first_row_values`, within square brackets, you are nesting a list within a new list, as its only element.

Comment: Thank you to you, Mad Physicist, and Anton vBR.  All of you made something clear I didn't understand previously.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just removing the square brackets should give you your result.

```
  writer.writerow(first_row_values)
```

Comment: sorry Kanchan...I plus'd one for you, but SamBG came first.\